# TV Alert after MA 200 crosses price and new candlestick opens

Tags: pine-script, alert, moving-average

The code gives me alert when MA 50 crosses over MA 200. I want it modify to receive alert based on the condition that MA 200 crosses price and a new candlestick opens above MA 200.

This is my current script:

```
// Define the inputs
src = input(close, title='Source')
maFastLength = input(50, title="Fast MA Length")
maSlowLength = input(200, title="Slow MA Length")

// Calculate moving averages
maFast = ta.sma(src, maFastLength)
maSlow = ta.sma(src, maSlowLength)

// Plot the indicators
plot(maFast, color=color.blue, title='50 MA')
plot(maSlow, color=color.red, title='200 MA')


buy_cond=ta.crossover(maFast, maSlow)

//plotshape(buy_cond?maFast:na,title = "Buy", style=shape.labelup,location=location.belowbar,color = color.green,text="Buy")
```

Comment: So what issue are you having?  e.g. what is it doing that is not meeting your requirements?  Or what are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to to create alerts based on when the price crosses above the 200-period MA and a new candlestick opens above the 200-period MA. Currently, my alert condition is set to 50/200 MA crossover.